# How often do we need to iterate this to get $\log (n)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Starting from $n$, I am wondering how often one has to iterate this in order to reach $\log n$. To be honest, I am not even quite sure whether this is the case at all:

$$n, \frac{n}{\log n}, \frac{n}{\log n \log(\frac{n}{\log n})},\frac{n}{\log n \log(\frac{n}{\log n}) \log (\frac{n}{\log n \log (\frac{n}{\log n})})}, \dotsc$$

So $x_1=n$, $x_{i+1}=\frac{x_i}{\log x_i}$ for $i \geq 2$.

For which $i$ do we have that $x_i=\log n$, if there is such an $i$ at all?

Thank you very much for any hint on how this can be solved!

And sorry for the bad tags: I have no idea which tags I should use!

Comment: Why do you whink you will ever get $\log n$?

Comment: at least twice a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x/\log x$. $e$ is the unique fixed point of $f$: $f(e)=e$. Moreover $f'(e)=0$; this implies that for an initial value $x_0$ close to $e$, the sequence of iterates $x_{n+1}=f(x_i)$ converges to the fixed point $e$. Using for instance graphical analysis you may check that the sequence converges to the fixed point for any initial value.

[image]